# utility to display contents of multiple short text files in single scrollable column

Tags: windows, search

Is there a Windows utility that will allow you to search against a large collection of small text files, and display not just a **list** of the found files, but the **contents** of all matching files in a single scrollable column, with lines separating each matching file, the results being sortable by different criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you borrow Unix utilities (e.g. by installing any of [Cygwin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/), [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/), [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) etc) then you can probably achieve that with a combination of `grep` and `cat`

```
 cat `grep -l target *.txt | sort {options}`
```

or maybe

```
 grep -l target *.txt | sort {options} | xargs -n 1 cat blanklines.txt
```

You can probably do it using Windows Powershell.